# «Впрочем» в конце предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Должна ли стоять запятая перед "впрочем"?
**Он был совсем побитым, таким же, как и я(,) впрочем.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, запятая перед «впрочем» необходима, так как в этом предложении оно является вводным словом, указывающим на то, что автор, высказывая свою мысль, испытывает нерешительность, сомнение.
Оно может быть заменено на «кстати сказать» или совсем убрано из предложения.

[ВПРОЧЕМ, вводное слово и союз](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_107)

**Он был совсем побитым, таким же, как и я, впрочем.**
*Я сегодня занят, как и всегда, впрочем.*

Стоит отметить, что предложения с «впрочем» в самом конце встречаются нечасто. Обычно вводное слово стоит или в начале предложения, или в середине.
*Он был совсем побитым, таким же, впрочем, как и я.*

Answer (score 1):

"Впрочем" всегда выделяется запятыми как вводное слово или вводный союз.

Исключением является "а впрочем" (связка вводного слова с союзом).